# Could not normalize path for file 'E:\WorkSpace\mapdemo\app\build\intermediates\mockable-Google Inc.:Google APIs:21.jar'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to run this app but it gives me error and I don't understand meaning of this error?

I have added google play service library also in build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:21'
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "act.com.mapdemo"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

my xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I'm running it gives me error:

```
Gradle 'mapdemo' project refresh failed

Error:Could not normalize path for file 'E:\WorkSpace\mapdemo\app\build\intermediates\mockable-Google Inc.:Google APIs:21.jar'.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

Answer (score 28):

Change your Android Gradle plugin version to:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.2'
}
```

This was a bug in earlier versions of the plugin that didn't properly escape illegal characters on Windows, and its fixed in v1.1.2:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=148912

Answer (score 3):

In android studio, Go to File-> project structure
Click on app/project name
Click on compile SDK version drop down, select a value
Select build tool versions if necessary.

This shall replace the compileSdkVersion with a integer value allowing you to proceed.

It actually gives the value as

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
```

So you can try this and see if it works for you. It worked for me.

Am on windows 7 android studio ver 1.1.0

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using windows and the filename contains a colon. But under windows a filename must not contain any of the following chars: /:*?"<>|

```
E:\WorkSpace\mapdemo\app\build\intermediates\mockable-Google Inc.:Google APIs:21.jar
                                                                 ^           ^
```

Comment: i don't have any colon in my filename

Comment: I count two colons in the filename showing in the error message. I marked it above.

Comment: Looks like [issue 148912](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=148912) in Android Open Source Project - Issue Tracker.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem while gradle is trying to run the project sync.

Error:

> Error:Could not normalize path for file ...\app\build\intermediates\mockable-Google Inc.:Google APIs:19.jar'.

Obviously, gradle is trying to create the file with the name "mockable-Google Inc.:Google APIs:19.jar". But it doesn't work in Windows, because the file name contains illegal characters (like ":" in my situation). I think the right question is, how to tell gradle, to avoid use illegal characters in the file name?

Thank you

P.S.
Building of the same Android project under Linux works fine.